# Using waitForCondition ( script,timeout ) in Selenium IDE

Tags: firefox, selenium

I recorded a script using the Selenium IDE extension for Firefox, and I would like to add the command waitForCondition. I see it takes two arguments: script and timeout. In Selenium IDE, I have 3 text fields for each command: the command name (I assume "waitForCondition"), the target, and the value. Where and how should I put the two arguments in this UI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
waitForCondition
var value = selenium.getText("foo"); value.match(/bar/);
3000
```

Answer (score 1):

Command: waitForCondition
Target:  var value = selenium.getText("foo"); value.match(/bar/);
Value:   3000